# Navigation Drawer is not getting closed when pressed back button for Support Library Revision 20

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-support-library

I am displaying ListView in Navigation Drawer. When Navigation Drawer is open and I press back hardware button then Navigation Drawer was not getting closed but the whole Activity got finished.

Interestingly instead of ListView when I directly used LinearLayout with Buttons, it was working fine. I checked out the Navigation Drawer sample provided by Android which uses ListView and surprisingly it works fine. After putting enough efforts, I identified that I was using Support Library V4 Revision 20 and the sample was using the old one, I still don't know the exact version of Support library used  by sample.

Has anybody faced the same problem or know the solution to fix this problem? I have temporarily solved this problem by overriding onBackPressed() API of Activity and closing Navigation Drawer explicitly from there. But still curious to understand the problem.